# Kendo ui pagination issue

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

i am working on a kendo ui grid http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html and i want to show only 5 records at a time and also show others through pagination so i use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: createRandomData(50),
                        pageSize: 5
                    },
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true
                    },
                    columns: [ {
                            field: "FirstName",
                    attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}        


                        } , {
                            field: "LastName",
                   attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}         
                        } , {
                            field: "City",
                   attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}           
                        } , {
                            field: "Title",
                   attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}           
                        } , {
                            field: "BirthDate",
                            template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #',
                   attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}           
                        } , {

                            field: "Age",
                   attributes:{"class": "table-cell"}       
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

pageable on line number 9 enables pagination but it enables every thing in footer bar and i dont need all i only need next and previous buttons adjecent to each other as well :). i also read out all its documentation http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration but i found no solution for it or may i missed it.

Comment: y my question is marked negative i thing its a valid question i did every thng and now i cannot revert from this plugin and i search my self alot for the solution

Comment: Why would you not want the page, and item count?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting Pager's info to false? Maybe this will help:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/pager#configuration

Answer (score 0):

stack,
try this Code or take it as example for pagination

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Ham", category: "Food" }
  ],
  page: 1,
  // a page of data contains two data items
  pageSize: 5
});
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var view = dataSource.view();
  console.log(view.length); // displays "2"
  console.log(view[0].name); // displays "Tea"
  console.log(view[1].name); // displays "Coffee"
});
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  pageable: {
        refresh: true
    },
  pageable:true,
    columns: [
        { field: "name", title: "Name", width: "100px" },
        { field: "category", title: "Category", width: "100px" },
    ],
    dataSource: dataSource
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [pager](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-pageable) documentation which shows how to disable certain options that are enabled by default. For example setting [numeric](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-pageable.numeric) to `false` would hide the numeric buttons.